# Does push technology work successfully on a mobile browser?

Tags: html, sencha-touch, push

If I had a webpage that had a square on it and if I was using push technology to update the coordinates of this square on the page, could I see these updates well in a mobile browser (how much in "real-time" would the responses be)? I want to use Sencha to make a board game and want to be able to use push messaging to update coordinates of items.  Is this at all possible? If so how scalable would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

It entirely depends on the specific browser on the mobile device. For example, the iPhone browser will most likely support more than one push tech, but something like Opera Mini or a simpler browser in an older phone might not.

Then again, older/less feature-rich browsers might not support "normal" Ajax either.

As for scalability, the type of the device used as the client does not have an effect on scalability.